# how to change the menu link path in drupal 8 based on the content?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I have a menu which contains few menu links such as report , attendance , others which are associated to a student, which is displayed in the view page with a path /student/{{student_id}}.And I also have seperate view pages for the menu links.
So I need to alter the path of the menu links so that I can link to views page associated to each menu link with student id as parameter,so that details about the particular student is displayed.
I came across topic like hook_preprocess_menu but couldn't find much documentation on how to use it in  my case.

Comment: Do you really have to pass that parameter? I mean, why don't you just read current user (id) on the landing page it self? You should be able to get current user in the view.

Comment: The user must be able to view details of every student. So yes I need to pass the parameter,so that details are displayed with respect to each student.